# Excel VBA: cell referencing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with cell referencing and I don't know if a solution exists.

Using VBA code I'm writing into a cell the reference to a different cell using the syntax:

```
activecell.formula = "=" & Cells(A1).address
```

Now I need to copy this formula for thousands of cells. Each cell should refer to a sequential `cell (A1,A2,A3....A120..)`.

The problem I have is that using

`Cells(A1).address`

it fixes the `Cells(A1)`. When I use the autofill function, I have thousands of cells all referencing the same `cells(A1)`, while I would need the reference to be dynamic and every time referencing the next `cell (A2,A3,A4..)`. And I need to use the autofill function because if I write the formula on each cell using a `loop` and fixed reference, it would take hours for the code to run (there are thousands of cells as explained before)

I should then use the relative reference format:

```
activecell.formulaR1C1 = ...
```

but the cells(A1)  are not always at the same distance from my activecell.

via VBA I can calculate how far each time it is from my `activecell`, but how can I use this data with `R1C1` notation?

so, lets say that using

```
row.count
```

function I can calculate the first cell to which I want to refer to,(this time) is on row 100 and column 3. So, I have: lastrow = 100, column = 3. Please note, the row 100 vary every time I run the macro. My `activecell` is `cells(5,5)`

this is what I would like to use:

```
Sub problemsolved ()

Dim lastrow as string
Dim RowL as string
Dim CoL as string

lastrow = activesheet.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row


cells(5,5).select

Rol = lastrow - 5
Col = 3 -5


activecell.formulaR1C1 = "=R[Rol]C[Col]"

selection.autofill Destination:=Range(cells(5, 5), cells(10005, 5))

end sub
```

assuming lastrow is = 100
I need to have the following result:

```
cell(5,5): =cells(100,3)
cell(6,5): =cells(101,3)
cell(7,5): = cells(102,3)
.....
cell(10005,5): = cells(10100,3)
```

of course, I've tried the syntax:

```
activecell.formulaR1C1 = "=R[lastrow]C[3]"
```

but it doesn't work, so how can I do it?
anybody has an idea?

thanks

Comment: Assume people are too busy to fully read all of this. You should also say what "doesn't work". i.e., what do you want to do, what have you tried, and what results did you get.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range(.Cells(5,5),.Cells(10005,5)).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[" & RowL & "]C[" & col & "]"
End With
```

no need for autofill

So

```
Sub problemsolved ()

Dim lastrow as Long
Dim RowL as Long
Dim CoL as Long

lastrow = activesheet.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row



Rowl = lastrow - 5
Col = 3 -5


With ActiveSheet
    .Range(.Cells(5,5),.Cells(10005,5)).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[" & RowL & "]C[" & col & "]"
End With 

end sub
```

Comment: Hi Scott, many thanks for your help. this is exactly what I was looking for, a way to work with relative notation but using some variables as well. You made my life easier today.. many many many thanks!